# Xamarin Sqlite filter textfield

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

I have decided to use Xamarin (Visual Studio element) and I want to have a large textfield (Say 5000 Characters) which when you click a button searches an Sqlite database for entries which contains some keywords in that textfield.

I have done a little bit of experimenting but I have so far only been able to do a direct match: I.E: Database has an entry called "green tree" and only if I enter the term "Green Tree" will it start matching
 I would want to be able to enter: "It was a cold day and the green tree shook in the wind" and for the database entry "Green Tree" to appear.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I forgot to add, I want the data to be already inputted into the database by the developer  (Myself) It will literally just be a searching application.

Comment: do you simply want to search for any word that is entered in the textfield?  Or do you want to identify only certain words that are keywords?

Comment: @Jason I want to search for any word entered.

Comment: Then you should be able to simply search for each keyword and OR them.   It might be helpful if you posted the actual code you are having problems with.

Comment: I haven't actually started the code yet. Just looking for a tutorial or way to do it. Bit of a newbie to this :)